# .NET Linq: How to eager load everything in an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a StudentDm that links to a Student table in database. The Student has like 20 navigation properties (ex. StudentEnrollments) and sub navigation properties. I need to load a subset of students but it is doing lazy loading for each student's navigation properties and it is very slow. What I wish to do is get a list of students from the dbContext with all its navigation properties already loaded (one trip to the database).

- Before you say this is bad practice: I need to do this in this specific situation because I need to export a subset of students to an excel sheet, and basically every single field is needed.
- I do not want to use .Include() one by one because that's not very maintainable. There are lots of navigation properties and Ill need to do this in other places too and for other entities.
- I do not wish to make a Data Transfer Object that basically has everything Student has, I think that's redundant and theres alot of fields.

Any expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well in your entities you could do: this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Comment: that would disable Lazy Loading for everything inside the context not just the desired entity.

Comment: Any chance you could post the schema? Because if I understood right that database call would have 20+ joins.

Comment: If you can post some sample code (including some "reduced" entity class declarations) we can help you better